# Unable to enable php-ast in docker php 7.3.5

Tags: php, docker

I'm trying to install php-ast extension to my project. This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.3.5-apache
RUN apt-get -yqq update \
    && apt-get -yqq install --no-install-recommends libzip-dev git
COPY ./php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
COPY ./php/php_errors.log /var/log/php_errors.log
COPY ./apache/error.log /var/log/apache2/error.log
COPY ./apache/access.log /var/log/apache2/access.log
COPY . /var/www/html
COPY ./apache/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
COPY ./mysql/my.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
COPY --from=composer:1.6.5 /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev libtool zip unzip \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo_mysql \
    && pecl install mcrypt-1.0.2 ast-1.0.1 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable mcrypt ast \
    && a2enmod rewrite
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
```

After I run this build and try to use ast, I get message that ast is not enabled. Would someone explain in plain English how should I install this extension on Docker php 7.3.5 or higher?

### Update

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
    appnew:
      build: .
      depends_on:
        - mysqlnew
      ports:
        - 8080:80
      networks:
        - app-net
      volumes:
        - ..:/var/www/html

      container_name: appnew
    mysqlnew:
        image: mysql:5.6
        ports:
          - 13317:3306
        environment:
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=XXXX_db
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=XXXXXX
        volumes:
          - mysql57data:/var/lib/mysql
          - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
#         - ./mysql/logs:/var/log/mysql/
        networks:
          - app-net
        container_name: mysqlnew
networks:
  app-net:
    driver: "bridge"
volumes:
  mysql57data:
    driver: "local"
```

And this is my php.ini:

```
date.timezone = Europe/London
memory_limit = 128M
post_max_size = 500M
upload_max_filesize = 200M
error_log = /var/log/php_errors.log
error_reporting = -1
log_errors = 1
```

Comment: Side question: what is the point of copying existing log files to your image ? And related to your initial question: are you sure that the php.ini you are copying is not part of (or entirely...) the problem your are experiencing ?

Comment: I copy log files to my docker directory in my project so I could see logs on my host machine live. I'll try to exclude php.ini from Dockerfile to check if it cause a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I used this Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.3.5-apache
RUN apt-get -yqq update \
    && apt-get -yqq install --no-install-recommends libzip-dev git
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev libtool zip unzip \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo_mysql \
    && pecl install mcrypt-1.0.2 ast-1.0.1 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable mcrypt ast \
    && a2enmod rewrite
```

ran the build and wrote `php -m` and this is the output

```
[PHP Modules]
ast
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
fileinfo
```

and you so many lines after that.

Comment: Strange. I've used the same Dockerfile and after php -m I get: ```root@454479178c88:/var/www/html# php -m
[PHP Modules]
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
fileinfo
filter
ftp
``` and no ast

Comment: what is the OS you are using? docker version?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04, Docker version 18.09.5, build e8ff056

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and Docker 18.09.6, build 481bc77.  By any chance you are using a low RAM machine? like 1GB or 2GB? I don't see why ast shouldn't be there,  while building I saw lot of make commands,so memory could be a factor.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I'm using 16 Gb RAM machine.

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: When I run it like `docker run -d --name my-running-app my-php-app` the ast is exist, but when I run it with my docker-compose, no. ((

Comment: Now I solved the problem but still don't know how it works. In my docker-compose file I've used image option like this: `image: phpapp` instead of `build: .` where phpapp is an image that I've build myself from your Dockerfile. And after that I got ast installed. Strange but I still don't understand why it doesn't work with `build .` option.

Comment: `./php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/` is replacing the php.ini file right. why are you replacing php.ini file?

Comment: I put there php settings using env variables

Comment: Buy the way, my own Dockerfile(that I've used in a description of my question) works too if I build an image from it and use `image: mybuild` option in my docker-compose fiile. But not your Dockerfile nor my Dockerfile doesn't work if I use `build: .` option in docker-compose file.